# Using configparser to remove section name only but retain its key and value pairs

Tags: python, parsing, ini, configparser

I am trying to remove the section from ini file but i want to retain that section's keys and values.

I tried to remove a section like this

```
with open('testing.ini', "r") as configfile:
    parser.read_file(configfile)

print(parser.sections())
parser.remove_section('top')
print(parser.sections())

with open('testing.ini', "w") as f:
    parser.write(f)
```

I m generating a ini file like this

```
[top]
username = 'rk'
pass = ''
```

expected Result of ini file

```
username = 'rk'
pass = ''
```

Comment: Can you provide example input, expected output, and observed behavior (all parts of a [MCVE])? As written, you haven't even said what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

configparser generally does not operate without sections, but you could construct a workaround by manually adding the section items into the config before removing the section altogether

```
with open('testing.ini', "r") as configfile:
    parser.read_file(configfile)

print(parser.sections())

text = '\n'.join(['='.join(item) for item in parser.items('top')])
with open('testing.ini', 'w') as config_file:
    config_file.write(text)

parser.remove_section('top')
print(parser.sections())
```